# TypeError: scrollto is undefined when using requireJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, requirejs

```
requirejs(['jquery', 'scrollto'], function($, scrollto) {
    var scroll = new scrollto.ScrollTo({
        dest: 500,
        speed: 2000
    });
```

> TypeError: scrollto is undefined

Im having problems in this error. I cant possibly identify where my problem is. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't really understand what you said,did you mean that I should use $('div') instaead of creating new object?

Comment: I tried but it went wrong again.And this time $ is undefined!

Comment: Yea thats because you need to implement jQuery @黄小龙

Comment: Can you show more code.?

Comment: thanks for your help,it was my mistake because I did not assert the name of scrollto like this "define ('jquery',function($){})".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should know that I should define a module like this 
**define(['jquery'],function($)){});**
instead of the wrong definition like this:
**define('jquery',function($){})**
Thanks to those who tried to slove my problem,this is my forst question,so please forgive my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you specify a scroll to:

```
$('div.pane').scrollTo(args);
```

You forgot to capitalize the T.. Plus it is not in the right syntax..

So instead of your way:

```
requirejs(['jquery', 'scrollto'], function($, scrollto) {
    var scroll = new scrollTo.ScrollTo({
        dest: 500,
        speed: 2000
    });
 })
```

Do this:

```
requirejs(['jquery', 'scrollto'], function($, scrollto) {
    $('div').ScrollTo({
        dest: 500,
        speed: 2000
    });
 })
```

Comment: I want to bind a click function on a element like this      $("#backTop").on('click', $.proxy(scroll.move, scroll));     but I met this peoblem which make the function dosen't work.